# invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use tensor.item() to convert a 0-dim tensor to a Python number

Tags: pytorch

I'm using PyTorch tutorial to calculate accuracy per class, and it is throw out an error that use `tensor.item()` which already is in `class_correct[target] += c[i].item()`

```
class_correct = list(0. for i in range(15))
class_total = list(0. for i in range(15))

with torch.no_grad():

    for ii, data in enumerate(test_loader): 

        t_image, target, classess, image_path  = data

        t_image = t_image.to(device)
        target = target.to(device)

        outputs = model(t_image)

        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        c = (predicted == target).squeeze()

        for i in range(4):
            target = target[i]
            class_correct[target] += c[i].item()
            class_total[target] += 1

for i in range(14):
    print('Accuracy of %5s : %2d %%' % (
        classes[i], 100 * class_correct[i] / class_total[i]))
```

any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, can you provide `c.shape`?

Comment: @Berriel when I get print(c.shape), the output is torch.Size([])

Comment: Do you understand the error now?

Answer (score 0):

Due to `c.shape`, `torch.Size([])` is not list. So it has error.
You can use use `c.item()`.